# auth_user.username gives 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: python, web2py

so im trying to save a sqlform to be saved with the user that filled the form.

```
db = DAL("sqlite://storage.sqlite")
db.define_table('Pedido',
            Field('Usuario',default=auth.user.username,readable=False, writable=False),
            Field('Nome','string'),
            Field('Telefone', 'string',),
            Field('Email', 'string'),
            Field('CEP','string'),
            Field('Rua', 'string'),
            Field('Tipo_de_cliente',requires=IS_IN_SET(['Cliente Fisico', 'Cliente Juridico'])),
            Field('Tipo_de_servico', requires=IS_IN_SET(['Reparo', 'Ajusto', 'Confecção','Outros'])),
            Field('Tipo_de_peca', requires=IS_IN_SET(['Camisa', 'Jaqueta', 'Saia','Calça','Vestido','Shorts','Camiseta'])),
            Field('Descricao', 'text'),
            Field('Data_de_recebimento_do_pedido','date'),
            Field('Data_de_entrega','date'),
            Field('Valor','double'),
            Field('Tipo_Pagamento',requires=IS_IN_SET(['Dinheiro','Cartão','Cheque'])),
            Field('Pago','boolean'))
```

with the above code only allow me to save the form if the user is logged otherwise it gives

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'
```

and my controller

```
@auth.requires_login()
def pedido():
Pedido = SQLFORM(db.Pedido)
Pedido.element('input[type=submit]')['_onclick'] = "return confirm('Deseja salvar?');"
if Pedido.process().accepted:
    response.flash = 'Salvo com sucesso'
return dict(Pedido=Pedido)
```

i already look all over and with every answer it just dont work,
anyone has the solution for this error? wherever i logout which i cant login again i must comment the usuario field so im able to login again

Comment: What is `auth.user.username ` ?

Comment: On line 3 in your first snippet it's `auth.user.username` and not `auth_user.username` as in the subject. Is one of them wrong?

Comment: auth.user.username is the username used to login i tried with id,first_name and other but since im using admin i tried with username which is admin just to test it can be anything really as long is identify the user

Comment: on line 3  auth_user.username it gives me a error saying 'auth_user' is not defined even logged and auth.user.uername accept the field as long the user is logged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`auth.user` is the record of the currently logged in user, so it is `None` when no user is logged in. You can change your code as follows:

```
Field('Usuario', default=auth.user.username if auth.user else None)
```